# how does the OS determine null pointer access without checking all pointer addresses?

Tags: pointers, operating-system, segmentation-fault, signals, memory-segmentation

It is known that the 0 address (which is marked as the macro 'NULL'), is not legal to access.
I was wondering how is it that the operating system (say linux) can determine when there is an access to null address, somewhere in the code, without having to access each and every pointer address in the code?
I assume it has something to do with signal and specifically, the "sigsegv" signal.

But I'm not sure how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a null pointer access is not necessarily invalid. Typically, either the operating system's program loader or the linker (depending upon the system) set up processes so that the the lowest page in the virtual address space is not mapped.

Many systems that do this also allow the application to map the first page, making a null reference valid.

The NULL pointer is checked the same way all other memory addresses are checked: through the logical address translation of the CPU.

Each time the processor accesses memory (ignoring caching) it looks up the address in the process's page table. If there is no corresponding entry, the processor triggers an access fault (that in Unix variants gets translated into a signal).

If there is an entry in the page table for the address, the processor checks the access allowed for the page. If you are in user mode and try to access a kernel protected page, that triggers a fault. If you are trying to write to a read only page, that triggers a fault. If you try to execute a non-executable page, that triggers a fault.

This is a rather lengthy topic. You need to understand logical memory translation (sometimes misnamed virtual memory) if you want to learn more on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers refer to *virtual address space*. In the virtual address space, each *page* of memory can be mapped to real physical memory. The operating system takes care of this mapping separately for each process.

When you access memory through a pointer, the CPU looks at the mapping for the virtual address your pointer specifies and checks if there is real, physical memory behind. Additional checks are done to verify that you have read or write access to that piece of memory, depending on the operation you are attempting.

If there is no memory mapped for that address, the CPU generates a hardware interrupt. The OS catches that interrupt and - usually - signals sigsegv for the calling process.

The zero page containing the `NULL` address is usually intentionally left unmapped, so that NULL pointer accesses, which usually result from programming errors, are easily trapped.

Answer (score 0):

The `Memory Management Unit` plays a key role in the exception triggering when a `NULL` pointer is dereferenced or an invalid address is accessed.

During the normal virtual-to-physical memory mapping process done by `MMU` on each `RAM` access, the undefined address is simply not found in the range of virtual addresses defined in the `MMU descriptors`. This can have catastrophic consequences if occurred in OS kernel-space, or just process kill and cleanup in the user-space domain.

Answer (score 0):

> *...how is it that the operating system (say linux) can determine when there is an access to null address, somewhere in the code, **without having to access each and every pointer address in the code**?*

Well, OS cannot determine a NULL dereference without accessing the pointer. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) for segmentation fault:

> In computing, a *segmentation fault* (often shortened to segfault) or access violation is a fault raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system (OS) about a memory access violation; on x86 computers this is a form of general protection fault. The OS kernel will in response usually perform some corrective action, generally passing the fault on to the offending process by sending the process a signal....

The memory access violation is a run-time incident, and unless there is an *invalid* access, there is no way OS will raise the signal to the process.

FWIW, a process is allowed to access the memory allocated for it (in virtual address space). Any address, outside the allocated virtual address space, if accessed, will generate a fault (through MMU) which in turn, generates the segmentation fault.

**TL;DR** - SIGSEV is generated on encountering the NULL-pointer dereference, not before that. Also, OS does not *detect* the erroneous access itself, rather it is informed to the OS by the [Memory Management Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) via [raising a fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_(computing)).

Comment: But is there any other way (aside from sigsegv) to find out a null derefrence?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer maybe a NULL check before dereferencing?

Answer (score 0):

Linux obtains this support from hardware. Processor is informed about the purpose of individual memory regions and their availability. If "unavailable" memory region is accessed the processor informs the operating system about the problem and the operating system informs the application.

It means two things:

- There is no software overhead related to checking all pointers against the NULL value.
- There is no precise check for allowed pointer values.

In other words, if your pointer points anywhere to the "available" memory then the hardware unit is unable to recognize the problem.